# $(x^{2022}+1)(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{2020})=2022\cdot x^{2021}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $S$ denote the set of all real values of $x$ for which $(x^{2022}+1)(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{2020})=2022\cdot x^{2021}$, then the number of elements in $S$ is $0/1/2/$infinite?

My attempt: $$(x^{2022}+1)(\frac{(x^2)^{1011}-1}{x^2-1})=2022\cdot x^{2021}$$
$$x^{4044}-1=2022\cdot x^{2023}-2022\cdot x^{2021}$$

Don't know how to proceed next.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but this is the first thing I saw: we can write the equation as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-1}{x^2-1}$$ where $y:=x^{2022}$.

Comment: @NoChance why do you assume this?

Comment: @NoChance- Common ratio is $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting this, now I have my glasses on...

Comment: Well, it’s a polynomial equation, so we know it doesn’t have infinitely many solutions. Performing algebra to get a polynomial equal to zero, we see the degree of the polynomial is odd, so we know it has at least 1 solution (in fact, by guessing, we can see x=1 is a solution).  But I’m not sure if there’s an easy way to confirm/deny the existence of another solution.

Comment: @Dave- Thanks to your input. I solved the integration, and got $y=x$ i.e.$x^{2021}=1$. $x$ being real, the only solution should be $x=1$.

Comment: @Joe. Thanks for the fantastic inputs.

Comment: @Ramit, you’re welcome.

Comment: @Joe Degree of the polynomial is even?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t remember why I would have thought the degree is odd. Clearly the degree is 4042.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left side is positive, thus any real root will be positive. $x=0$ is not a solution.

If you multiply everything out you find that the polynomial is symmetric under degree reversion, so with some root $x$ also $x^{-1}$ is a root.

If you divide by $x^{2021}$, the left side will turn into a convex function with a minimum at $x=1$, while the right side is constant.

By inspection, $x=1$ is a solution.

Being a minimizer makes the root at $x=1$ into a double root. There are no other roots.

---

The polynomial equation can also be written as 
$$
0=\sum_{k=0}^{1010}(x^{2k}-2x^{2021}+x^{4042-2k})=\sum_{k=0}^{1010}x^{2k}(x^{2021-2k}-1)^2
\\
=(x-1)^2\sum_{k=0}^{1010}x^{2k}(x^{2020-2k}+x^{2019-2k}+...+x+1)^2
$$
which again is twice the linear factor for $x=1$ and then a positive factor with no additional root.

Comment: Doesn't Descartes' rule of signs give an odd number of roots, counting multiplicities?

Comment: No, you have a sign sequence $+,...,+,-,+,...,+$, this only has 2 sign variations, thus 2 or zero roots.

Comment: If you mean the "compactified" polynomial from the question, this has indeed 3 sign variations, according to its triple root at $1$. Note that one of those is introduced by multiplying with $x^2-1$, so the original polynomial again has an even number of positive roots.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  I understand now.

Comment: The given polynomial has just one sign change, so, it would have just one positive root, right?

Comment: @ramit: You have to put the coefficients of the fully expanded polynomial in a degree ordered sequence, leaving out the zero coefficients. Then from degree 2020 to 2021 is a sign change from + to -, from degree 2021 to 2022 is a sign change from - to +, this makes 2 sign changes.

Comment: @LutzL- Oh,thanks. But then how come this rule is not satisfied? i.e., we are neither  getting 2 positive roots nor zero.

Comment: @Ramit : These counts are always with multiplicity, as the sign structure is invariant to small perturbations of the non-zero coefficients, and does thus not distinguish the generic case of simple roots from the exceptional case of roots with higher multiplicity.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that equation does not have negative roots (otherwise left side is positive and right side is negative). Now, note that for every $x\geq 0$ from the AM-GM inequality we obtain that
$$
(x^{2022}+1)(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2020})=1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{4042}\geq 
\\
\geq 2022\sqrt[2022]{x^{0+2+\ldots+4042}}=2022x^{2021}.
$$
Therefore, if $x$ is a solution to the equation then we have $1=x^2=\ldots=x^{4042}$. Hence, the equation has only one root $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements in $S$ is $1$. **Proof**. From $(x^{2022}+1)(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{2020})=2022\cdot x^{2021}$ we see that $x>0$. Let $g(x)=2x^{2023}+2021-2023x^{2}$. Then $\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=4046x(x^{2021}-1)$ and $g(1)=0$. Consequently $g(x)>0$ if $x>1$ and $g(x)<0$ if $0<x<1$. Let $f(x)=x^{4044}-1+2022(x^{2021}-x^{2023})$. Then $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=2022x^{2020}g(x)$ and $f(1)=0$.Consequently $f(x)>0$ if $x>1$ and $f(x)<0$ if $0<x<1$. 
Consequently $x=1$ is a only thing solution.